# json.map is not a function

Tags: json, node.js

json.map is not a function - Getting this Error while using Node-fetch

GET Method

JSON Fetch result

```
{"status":200,"email":"email@example.com","domain":"example.com","mx":false,"disposable":false,"alias":false,"did_you_mean":null,"remaining_requests":99}
```

I want to Print this on Node CLI Table

```
    const printContent = json => {
    console.log()

      const group = json.map(g => [
        g.status,
        g.email
      ])

      const table = new Table({
        head: ["Name", "Email"],
        colWidths: [20, 20]
      })

      table.push(...group)
      console.log(table.toString())
  }
```

Comment: map works on array, not on object, you're probably looking for Object.keys() or Object.entries()

Comment: Post Updated...

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code where you actually get and parse the JSON?  I'm guessing you're calling .map on the string not a JS object.

Comment: `https://www.validator.pizza/email/email@example.com`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

map only works on arrays.  Is json a single object? If so, try:

```
  const group = [json].map(g => [
    g.status,
    g.email
  ])
```

That will return a dual element array with your mapped object.

If you want an object, try:

```
const group = Object.assign({}, {status:g.status, email:g.email})
```

Comment: Thanks perfect it's Working :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON first in order to get a JS object. However the map() function works on arrays. I would simply just do it without map, since you do not fetch an array:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(json);
const group = [obj.status, obj.email];
```